# Property P for von Neumann algebras with cyclic vector

Tags: operator-theory

Definition : (J. Schwartz) A von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{A},$ acting on the Hilbert space $H,$ has property (P) if for each $T\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ the weakly closed convex hull of the set consisting of the elements $$U T U^*, U\in\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{A})$$ has non-void intersection with the commutant $\mathcal{A}^\prime,$ where $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{A})$ is the set of unitary operators in $\mathcal{A}.$

Question: If $\mathcal{A}$ is a von Neumann algebra with cyclic vector, then is it true that $\mathcal{A}$ has property (P)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not necessarily true. A von Neumann algebra on a separable Hilbert space has property (P) if and only if it is amenable (or injective or a couple of other equivalent conditions). In particular, the group von Neumann algebra $L(G)\subset B(\ell^2(G))$ has the cyclic vector $\delta_e$, but it is amenable only if $G$ is amenable.

I don't have a good reference, but the equivalence of amenability of $G$ and property (P) for $L(G)$ is proven in J. Schwartz, *Two finite, non-hyperfinite, non-isomorphic factors*, Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 16 (1963).

Comment: Thank you so much @MaoWao. I found also the  counterexample in Sakai's book (C*-algebras and W*-algebras) of $L(\mathbb{F}_2),$ where $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the free group on two generators.

Comment: which suits your answer since this group is not amenable.